# How to stop WPF controls (using expanders) heights expanding to parent's height in ItemControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

I want to have a view of UserControls hostest within an ItemControl, using a WrapPanel as the ItemsPanelTemplate, for example, I Have

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Margin="5">No to load</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Name="NumBox" Width="80" Margin="5">1000</TextBox>
        <Button Width="80" Height="25" Click="LoadClick">Load</Button>
        <Button Click="ClearClick" Margin="5">Clear</Button>
    </StackPanel>

    <ScrollViewer  Grid.Row="1"   Margin="3" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
        <ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:TestControl2></local:TestControl2>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>

</Grid>
```

And the TestControl2  is defined as follows..

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfWrapPanelTest.TestControl2"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"              
         mc:Ignorable="d" Height="Auto" Width="120" Margin="10">
<Border Background="Bisque" CornerRadius="10" Height="Auto">
    <StackPanel>
        <Expander Header="Options 1" ExpandDirection="Down">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock>Item1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>Item2</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Expander>
        <Expander Header="Options 2" ExpandDirection="Down">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock>Item1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>Item2</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>Item3</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>Item4</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Expander>
    </StackPanel>
 </Border>
</UserControl>
```

The problem here is when I expand one of the expanders.. as well the the control expanded growing in height (which I want), all the other controls in the same row also grow in height.

Is there a ways to stop all the other controls in the same row from growing in height?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: unable to reproducde your problem, try to explain with figure.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan I reproduce, maybe you need add some items in 'Data' in codebehind. And the 1st answer solved it.

Comment: @LeiYang I can't see my controls growing in Height. http://share.pho.to/9u3cc

Comment: @LeiYang Sorry, now I understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that the `VerticalAlignment` property of a `FrameworkElement` defaults to `Stretch`. You need to break this at some point in the tree by specifying some other Vertical Alignment.  My recommendation would be to change your DataTemplate to:

```
<local:TestControl2 VerticalAlignment="Top"></local:TestControl2>
```